# Vue $on fires console.log but won't chance local properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a window.event.$emit that fires a 'selfAddLike' and 'selfRemoveLike' event. When this event is "consumed" in the parent component, it will console.log('hey'), but the changing of local properties does not work. For example: this.isFavorited = true won't trigger, along with this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount + data;

Here is some code:

```
    export default {

    components: {
      'editor': Editor,
      'favorite': Favorite
    },

    props: ['reply'],
    
    data() {
        return {
            favoritesCount: this.reply.favoritesCount,
            isFavorited: this.reply.isFavorited,
            }
        }
    },

    created() {

        window.events.$on('selfAddLike', function (data) {
            this.isFavorited = true;
            this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount + data;
        });

        window.events.$on('selfRemoveLike', function (data) {
            this.isFavorited = false;
            this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount - data;
        });
    },

    }
}

export default {

    props: ['reply'],

    data() {
        return {
            isFavorited: this.reply.isFavorited,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        toggle() {
            if (this.isFavorited) {
                axios.delete('/replies/' + this.reply.id + '/favorites');
                this.isFavorited = false;
                window.events.$emit("selfRemoveLike", 1);
            } else {
                axios.post('/replies/' + this.reply.id + '/favorites');
                this.isFavorited = true;
                window.events.$emit("selfAddLike", 1);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change to arrow function to allow access to the component `this`

```js
window.events.$on('selfAddLike', (data) => { // use arrow function here
     this.isFavorited = true;
     this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount + data;
});

window.events.$on('selfRemoveLike', (data) => { // use arrow function here
     this.isFavorited = false;
     this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount - data;
});
```

Comment: Was about to write that. Either do that or define `const self = this` in `created()` hook (above both event listeners), and use it instead of `this`

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would only select that individual reply. It looks like all my Replys are favorited upon the emit now.